# Joining multiple tables in single join transformation in Data Flow (Azure Data Factory v2)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

Let us take sample SQL as:

```sql
    select a.a1
    from
    alice a,
    bob b,
    chris c,
    don d
    where 
    a.a1 = b.b1 ,
    and b.b1 = c.c1 ,
    and c.c1 = d.d1 ;
```

When creating [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create) (Azure Data Factory v2) to handle inner joins in the above query we need to add 2 different [join transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join). Is there any other way to use single join transformation for these multiple inner joins ???

The above query is just a sample, typically there can be 10 to 30 joins in a single query.

PS: This question is strictly seeking answers which include [**Azure Data Flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview), so please read about it before answering.

Azure Data Flow (not to be confused with Azure Data Factory) / Data Flow / Mapping Data Flow allows users to develop graphical data transformation logic without writing code and it does not support any language other than own [expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions)

Comment: I bet that adding some more details and rephrasing your question would have a massive positive impact on the quality of answers, as for now you have a month old question with a solid bounty and no answer accepted or at least upvoted.